# Checkbox not firing in Gridview with javascript message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a checkbox within a gridview. 
On CheckChanged event, it sends updates to the database. It works fine, until I added a message to ask the user if he/she wanted to proceed.

When the checkbox is clicked, the message is displayed, the user click on OK and the checkchanged event is not fired. However when the page is refreshed, the checkchanged event fires.

I have tried many combination, but nothing seems to be working.

This is the gridview with the 2 checkboxes:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" PageSize="20"
ShowStatusBar="false" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="false" DataKeyNames="RowType, QID"
AllowFilteringByColumn="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" ShowGroupPanel="false" Skin="" Width="100%"
CssClass="GVResult" SelectedItemStyle-CssClass="SelectedStyle" RenderMode="Lightweight"
OnRowDataBound="GV_ItemDataBound" OnRowCommand="GV_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionNo" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionNo") %>' runat="Server" CssClass='<%# Eval("CSS") %>' Enabled="False" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQID" runat="Server" Value='<%# Eval("QID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMarker1" Text='<%# Eval("Marker1") %>' runat="Server" CssClass='<%# Eval("CSS") %>' Enabled="true" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ckMarker1" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckMarker1") %>' runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ckMarker_CheckedChanged" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMarker2" Text='<%# Eval("Marker2") %>' runat="Server" CssClass="Label_100_White" Enabled="False" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ckMarker2" Checked='<%# Eval("CheckMarker2") %>' runat="Server" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ckMarker_CheckedChanged" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The messages for the checkboxes are added on the gridview RowDataBound:

```js
protected void GV_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row is GridViewRow & e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow Item = e.Row as GridViewRow;

            CheckBox ckMarker1 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ckMarker1");
            CheckBox ckMarker2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ckMarker2");

 ckMarker1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: var answer = confirm('Do you want to proceed with the changes');return answer;"); 
 ckMarker2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: var answer = confirm('Do you want to proceed with the changes');return answer;");            }
    }
```

And this is the checkbox change event:
Instead of firing after the message is displayed, it fires when the pages is refreshed.

```js
protected void ckMarker_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DTO.FinalMarkingUpdate f = new DTO.FinalMarkingUpdate();
    BLL.AllocMQuestion F = new BLL.AllocMQuestion();
    CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow Item = (GridViewRow)ck.NamingContainer;

    f.OrgID = this.OrgID;
    f.AssessID = this.AssessID;
    f.MarkerNo = int.Parse(ck.ID.Substring(8, 1));
    f.QID = int.Parse(((HiddenField)Item.FindControl("hfQID")).Value);
    f.IsMarker = ck.Checked;
    F.UpdateMarkerAndChecker(f);

    DataSource();
}
```

Comment: Does your `gridview` is inside any `updatepanel`?

Comment: Yes the gridview is in an update panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attribute like below to make it work. It will return `true` for confirm `dialogbox` ok click and return false for confirm `dialogbox` cancel click.

```
protected void GV_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row is GridViewRow & e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow Item = e.Row as GridViewRow;

            CheckBox ckMarker1 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ckMarker1");
            CheckBox ckMarker2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ckMarker2");

            ckMarker1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm('Do you want to proceed with the changes')) return false;");
            ckMarker2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (!confirm('Do you want to proceed with the changes')) return false;");
        }
    }
```